# How do I play an album starting from nth song in iTunes

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

I'm new to iTunes and trying to make sense of it's difficult UI. Let's say I have Bob Dylan Essential's, and I want to play it starting from 2nd song of disc 2. I double click this song in my library but, instead of playing all songs starting from this one, iTunes shuffles the entire album into the Play Next section. I've takes a screenshot with the result:

[image]

How do I play all songs in order, starting from a particular one?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just a case of persuading iTunes to actually **Stop** rather than **Pause**

When you first launch iTunes it is Stopped - the top menu doesn't contain any current song info. If at that point you hit Play, it will actually start from just the first song in the list & continue on down the page [assuming you don't have shuffle enabled, of course].
If you double-click any track instead, then it will do the same, from that track - which is what you want...so...

To make it actually Stop, whilst it's playing, hold  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  & click the Pause button **II**
<sub>You might also notice the rewind button changes to a kind of 'orbiting' icon - that's to start Genius based on the current track - but not relevant to this issue.</sub>

Once stopped, it ought to return to 'normal' behaviour.

If it doesn't, an alternative is to enable, then disable shuffle. That should also revert to linear play mode.

Comment: Well, iTunes was freshly started when I tried the scenario I described, it wasn't in a paused state. I also took care to clear the Up Next queue before trying it.
I will try your suggestion though.

Comment: Then you're down to toggling shuffle & also toggling Genius from the 'orbit' can help. I find it can get itself confused sometimes, & it seems to be just a case of trying to get it back to some kind of default state. Mine was the same when I first looked at it today, pseudo-random next-up list